# What's the XXXBundle.php file for?

Tags: symfony

In the root of every Symfony 2 bundle is a file `XXXBundle.php`, where "XXX" is your bundle name. What's that file for?

Comment: `-1` guy here: I found the OP's lack of research disturbing. This kind of questions usually display troubling unwillingness to learn or research or to just do the damn thing...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In short it lets Symfony2 know that the folder around this class follows certain Bundle structure convention (i.e. Symfony2 knows that it can find controller classes in /Controller). It also acts as a general go-to class for stuff like DIC configs.

For more info look into `Symfony\Component\HttpKernel\Bundle`

Comment: @Inori, whats DIC? Dependency Injection Config? If so, isn't that under `Resources\config\services.yml` for example? Apart from DIC config, do I put bundle bootstrap or helper functions there?

Comment: @jiewmeng DIC = Dependency Injection Container. in services.yml you specify its configs, but there has to be a class that tells symfony2 how and where and when to look for it :) And no, you shouldn't really put any functions inside that class. There are some use cases, but very rare. For now just imagine that this file doesn't exist. (I'm using symfony2 for a year and there was only 1 time where I needed to change one tiny thing in that file) As for "helper function" - that's most likely a job for twig extension

Comment: @Inori, I am not creating a view helper. More of a function that I may use across different controllers/classes. Perhaps, I can try to put then in `/BundleFolder/Helpers` or something like that